# Fileinfo object

Tags: c#

If I'm `using System.IO;` and have run the following:

```
    string myPathway = @"R:\Hello.pdf"
    FileInfo x = new FileInfo(myPathway);
```

Is there a method so I can reuse the object x but pointed at a different file located at "mySecondPathway", or do I create a new FileInfo object `y` ?

Comment: You can reuse the _variable_, but not the _object_.  If you're worried about memory usage, don't.

Comment: +1 (only thing that worries me is how long it'll take before I'm confident in this language...seems mighty big.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FileInfo x = new FileInfo("R:\\Hello.pdf"); // you forgot to escape the backslash
x = new FileInfo("anotherFile.txt"); // just reassign it
```

Note that reassignment doesn't re-use the actual object in-memory, but the `x` just now refers to the `anotherFile.txt` file.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to reuse a `FileInfo`-object, you need to create a new one. You can just reassign `x` with `x = new FileInfo(mySecondPath);` though.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. You have to create a new object, but can reuse `x`, as `x = new FileInfo(mySecondPath);`